# Job application asks to list relevant experience

Tags: applications

On the description page of a job application, it asks to list all relevant experience. On the actual application where I list my experience, it just says “work experience.”

This is a teaching job application that requires a teaching credential.

Would it be fair to say relevant experience would be jobs that I’ve held with a teaching credential only?

Edit: I forgot to mention this was a job pool application. It wasn’t for a specific job but was to be entered into a applicant pool of jobs come up.

I did upload a resume with several non credentialed jobs, but left some of those jobs off when filling out the “work experience” part in the application.

I guess what I’m trying to come down to is, since the application didn’t specifically state “list all jobs in the past 5 years,” or “list past three employers,” that stating to list relevant experience is somewhat of a gray area.

Comment: Don't forget: Any position where you were working in the field of which you teach could be indirectly relevant also.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be fair to say relevant experience would be jobs that I’ve
>   held with a teaching credential only?

In general, "relevant" has a bit broader meaning in this context. Any experience related to teaching - with or without an actual teaching credential - could be relevant.

But since the application just says "work experience", I'd suggest that you include all of your work experience. By definition that includes all relevant experience, plus any other experience (some of which may even be marginally relevant).

That way, you won't be missing anything that might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What if I am one year out of college? Do I list any jobs while in college? There are some non credentialed jobs that I was let go from that I would rather not put on the application.

Comment: Agree - If I did research work and published papers in a physics journal regarding work on the CERN accelerator in the search for the Higgs bosun, and I later got my teaching certification and applied for a high school physics position, that work would certainly be "relevant" to teaching physics. If they wanted exact "already did this job" experience, only, the word "relevant" would not have been used.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be fair to say relevant experience would be jobs that I’ve held with a teaching credential only?

I would not think so, as **the experiences you've had in the past have helped improve your teaching skills and knowledge, regardless of you having a credential or not.**

Of course, for *this* application it is necessary to have a credential, but not having so does not mean your past experience is not relevant.